# Loading Bar on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please I'm trying to knockoff a loading bar on my site, I have searched through the files, still can't find it. I also tried inspecting using google chrome, but I couldn't target the loader. Kindly help out

[Click here for to visit website.](http://crewresolution.com/public/)

Comment: Please show the code of your page.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="pace  pace-inactive">
    <div class="pace-progress" style="width: 100%;" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99">
        <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pace-activity"></div>
</div>
```

Remove this html construct. There also should be a javascript/css which triggers the loading bar. You can remove that too.

It's inside your head:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it worked

Answer (score 0):

just go the HTML of your page. there from the top, search for `<body>` tag. Just below it you'll find this :

```
<div class="pace  pace-inactive"><div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="pace-activity"></div></div>
```

Remove all these lines and you'll be fine

and remove these two lines in your `<head>` tag

```
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think whatever you are asking to remove it's possible because this code is dynamically getting attached to the application code in index.html by pace plugin. So, you won't find this lines of code in index.html.

Comment: I have edited my answer. check now

Comment: @ARITRA. Still I believe you won't find "pace pace-inactive" class or div in the index.html, it's dynamically getting attached.

Comment: just remove those two lines from <head> tag and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove Pace library/plugin from your index.html in head section 
 & from assets folder inside your application.

```
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
```